# Python Max method giving wrong result

Tags: python

I am trying to check for the longest word in a Python list using the `max` method, but the result seems strange to me.

```
max(['hello', 'there', 'people'])
```

returns `'there'` instead of `'people'`.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you haven't specified anything different, it is using the default comparison for strings, which is lexicographic. So `there` is maximum because it is last alphabetically.

If you want to use length instead, you need to specify that.

```
>>> max(['hello', 'there', 'people'], key=len)
'people'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you tell it otherwise, `max` will use the default sort method to find the largest, which means sorting lexicographically - the character code of `t` is higher than `p`, so that's what's returned. If you want to sort by length, you need to tell it:

```
max(['hello', 'there', 'people'], key=len)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `max` is simply testing to see which string compares highest, so the one that comes lexically last:

```
>>> max(['hello', 'there', 'people'])
'there'
```

To compare lengths you must specify a different key.

```
>>> max(['hello', 'there', 'people'], key=len)
'people'
```